# ScriptDB Visualiser not working ?Caja

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

I have been using the excellent [ScriptDB visualiser](https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/ScriptDbVisualizer) to help develop a google-apps-script.

This uses the HTMLService and worked last week, but now I cannot get it to work.
The HTML still is served & loads, but no javascript runs. When a button is clicked the error console (in firefox) gives the error;
**Error: shouldn't happen: ES5/3 object passed to makeDOMAccessible

Source File: https://ssl.gstatic.com/caja/5346m/es53-taming-frame.opt.js?debug=1
Line: 1788**

I suspect some Caja issue, but I went to the Caja playground and could not make any headway.

Any suggestions how to get this working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message suggests, this shouldn't happen.

That is, this is an internal bug in Caja or possibly Google Apps Script's use of Caja. Please [report it on the Caja issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry) including a (preferably as short as you can make it) example of HTML which causes the error (preferably when run in the Caja Playground, but if not then in Google Apps Script).

Comment: Thanks. I reported the issue here [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1718) with cutdown code.